# File input added with register_setting in Wordpress won't upload file

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, custom-theme

I have created a custom options page for my Wordpress theme and I need to add a file input field through which a MP4 video can be uploaded (~15Mb). Problem is the `$_FILES` variable is always empty.

```
/**
 * Custom theme form
 */
function theme_option_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Cusstom Theme Options</h1>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
        settings_fields("theme-options-grp");
        do_settings_sections("theme-options");
        submit_button();
    ?>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Custom theme settings
 */
function add_theme_menu_item() {
    add_theme_page(
        "Theme Options",
        "Theme Options",
        "manage_options",
        "theme-options",
        "theme_option_page",
        null,
        99
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_theme_menu_item');

/**
 * Theme section
 */
function theme_section_description() {
    echo '<p>Options for this theme</p>';
}

/**
 * File upload
 */
function display_product_teaser()
{
    ?>
    <input type="file" name="product_teaser" accept=".mp4" value="<?php echo get_option('product_teaser'); ?>" />
    <?php
}

/**
 * Handler for the uploaded file
 */
function handle_product_teaser_upload($option) {
    // $_FILES is empty here !!!
    if (!empty($_FILES["product_teaser"]["tmp_name"])) {
        $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["product_teaser"], array('test_form' => false));
        $temp = $urls["url"];
        return $temp;  
    }

    return $option;
}

/**
 * Add theme settings fields
 */
function custom_theme_settings() {
    add_settings_field("product_teaser", "Product teaser (mp4)", "display_product_teaser", "theme-options", "first_section");
    register_setting( 'theme-options-grp', 'product_teaser', 'handle_product_teaser_upload' );
}

add_action('admin_init', 'custom_theme_settings');
```

I tried adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form but then when I submit it, I end up in *wp-admin/options.php*, where all settings are displayed, instead of coming back to the custom options form for the theme.